# Cant fetch the name and date of image

Tags: android, gridview, android-sdcard

I am new in Android and im working on Grid View which i have implemented when i click an image in the grid view i have the path of the image in a variable "path" of type String it is something like i.e /mnt/sdcard/me.jpg how can i fetch the name of the image i.e "me.jpg" and the date of the image kindly tell me any function or code for this purpose.i am mentioning the code to give an idea of the path

```
gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            path = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    path, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first search on google then only post question....

```
File file = new File(path );
String name = file.getName(); //here you get the name of the image

Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified()); // here you get the creation or last modified date of the file
Log.i("File last modified @ : "+ lastModDate.toString());
```

Comment: That is really harsh i did google a lot but i was going in the wrong direction and one more thing there is an error in your last line.Still thnks for the reply.

Comment: The method i(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Thnkx but what is the purpoe of LOG.i() when we can show the date via toast

Comment: your wish log.v() if for printing purpose like as system.out.println();